# Visual Studio OpenCV error C2664

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

```
error C2664: 'double cv::threshold(cv::InputArray,cv::OutputArray,double,double,int)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'IplImage *' to 'cv::InputArray'
```

How to solve this type of error?

Comment: Which language? What have you tried?

Comment: please do **not** use IplImages. opencv moved to c++ half a decade ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing OpenCV's C and C++'s APIs. Since you're using C++, use `cv::Mat` instead of `IplImage *`, which is also recommended.

If you have to use `IplImage *`, convert it to `cv::Mat` first before calling `cv::threshold`:

```
IplImage *ipl_img;
cv::Mat mat_img(ipl_img);
```

And, then, use `mat_img` to pass into `cv::threshold`.